# storage limits for contents on SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

What are the storage limits for contents on SFMC?

On the pricing sheet, there is limited storage for Data Extensions depending on the edition.

But what about Contents? Are they included in that storage limit?

Comment: Maybe try contacting your Account Executive or Success Manager to be 100% sure. Personally I've never really heard about storage in the context of Marketing Cloud as an issue (while it's important for Sales Cloud) even when I took part in setting requirements for new contracts.